# using SED to replace 'price' with 'g:price'

Tags: sed

this is returning the error indicating that ':' is a bad character, i used this:
sed "s/price/ /g:price//g" file.txt > outputfile.txt
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping it:

```
 sed "s/price/g\:price/g" file.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: probably works so i will accept it, i just used sed "s#price#\g:price#g", thanks anyway...

Comment: @bboyreason: No, this answer doesn't work. It will give an error message.

Comment: it worked for me on a txt file in bash on osx with a bunch of stuff installed through macports, like octave

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change "price" to "g:price" , there is really no need to escape the ":". Also , use single quotes (unless you want to interpolate variables)

```
$ echo "price" | sed 's/price/g:price/'
g:price
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has not to do with the `:` character - your command that is wrong for other reasons:

s/price/ /g:price//g

What this command is doing is to replace all `prince` instances by a whitespace:

s/price/ /g

since the rest of the command makes no sense, `sed` cannot execute it. What you should do is to remove the `/` just after `price` and to remove one of the `/` at the end of the command. The result will be the one presented by @kurumi answer:

```
s/price/g:price/
```

HTH